# LPM equivalent for ATtiny10?

Tags: avr, memory, attiny

I would like to load some data from the program memory (e.g. a sine table) on my t10. Like on other AVRs the lpm command is for that purpose but it seems not to exist on the t10. I saw this crazy project (https://github.com/dop3j0e/noiseplug/blob/master/avr/noiseplug.s) which is for a t9 (same core as t10 but without ADC). They have just 32byte SRAM and if you scroll down you see a lot of tables which definetly would not fit into 32byte. They load thier tables like so:

```
157     ; note = notes[bassline[bassptr]]
158     ldi  r30, lo8(bassline)
159     add  r30, r20
160     ld   r20, Z
161     ldi  r30, lo8(notes)
162     add  r30, r20
163     ld   r21, Z+
164     ld   r20, Z
```

and my code looks like:

```
ldi     ZL,     LOW(prog_mem*2)  ; set pointer to
ldi     ZH,     HIGH(prog_mem*2) ; table address
ld      r16,    Z+               ; patern = (Z), post inc

prog_mem:
.db 0b11110000, 0b11001100
```

but simulating it 0xF0 doesnt appear in r16. I already had a look at atmel.com/webdoc/avrassembler/avrassembler.wb_LPM.html and atmel.com/webdoc/avrassembler/avrassembler.wb_LD.html but both werent enlightning.

Can anyone tell me where I made the mistake? Did they use another trick? Is it even possible to get data from program memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the ATtiny4/5/9/10 datasheet, section 5, "Memories", subsection 5.1, "In-System Re-programmable Flash Program Memory":

> Constant tables can be allocated within the entire address space of program memory. Since program memory can
>   not be accessed directly, it has been mapped to the data memory. The mapped program memory begins at byte
>   address 0x4000 in data memory (see Figure 5-1 on page 15). Although programs are executed starting from
>   address 0x000 in program memory it must be addressed starting from 0x4000 when accessed via the data
>   memory.

So you will need to add 0x4000 to the address in flash to access the same location via the data bus.